# How can I define custom build command instead of "make all" in a C++ Eclipse projects?

Tags: eclipse, makefile, eclipse-cdt

I imported an existing make file project to eclipse. I want to compile the code with a custom make argument instead of `make all` like `make test`. How can I add these different make calls to project in Eclipse Luna?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer from URaoul helped me find another answer. (**Update**: Later I realized that the more correct answer than mine is to use "Build Configurations")

There is a menu command "Make Targets". You can find it in menu: `Project/Make Targes`. Or you can simply press "Shift-F9".

So you need to create one or a few targes. So for my makefile:

```
.PHONY: all test autotest

all: program

program: main.o
    $(CXX) $(LDFLAGS) -o $@ $^
test:
    ./program

autotest:
    echo "Autotests"
    ./program
    echo "Autotests completed"

clean:
    rm *.o program
```

I created three targets in "Make target":
[image]

One of them is "run my autotests" which has a custom build command:

[image]

One of them is all, which has a default command:
[image]

Comment: Hey, that works like a charm! Thanks a lot! Do you know how I could run it in the eclipse cdt though... I can do from the command line using `./project args`, but don't know how to do it from eclipse cdt... I have a main function in the .cc file. I click the run button, it only builds the project. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

From http://help.eclipse.org/luna/topic/org.eclipse.cdt.doc.user/getting_started/cdt_w_import.htm?cp=10_1_3

Open the project properties (right mouse on project name in the Project Explorer view and select Properties at the bottom on the context menu).

On the C/C++ Build Page, on its Builder Settings tab, uncheck Use default build command and change the makecommand to make -f hello.mak or whatever command you need.

Answer (score 0):

In any project you have main file usually "makefile." You must edit this file.

if you look through the main makefile you'll find something like this:

```
all: #usually with dependencies.
```

This is a make rule, to make your own just add it in the same way:

```
test: #some command or dependency.
```

Then when you do make test it will do what you asked it to.

check this out for some more examples and better understanding on makefile rules.
[GNU Make](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Rule-Example)

here's some stuff for making new files in eclipse if you haven't seen it yet.
[makefile in Eclipse](http://help.eclipse.org/luna/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.cdt.doc.user%2Fgetting_started%2Fcdt_w_newproj.htm)

Answer (score 0):

You can create a external tool which runs any command line command you can think of. Just click in arrow near the [image: External tools] icon and select "External Tools Configurations".